# Bootstrap footer covering content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, sticky-footer

I have been trying to fix this issue for days. I see a lot questions about it, but none of the solutions seem to be working for me.

I have a website that has a Bootstrap 3 front end. I want a sticky bottom footer and I'm using Bootstrap's `navbar navbar-fixed-bottom` styles to achieve this. It is working, but the problem is that the content will overlap with the footer when there is not enough room. I want to be able to scroll the content with the footer and header fixed and I don't want the footer to scroll with the content.

[Here is the site](http://edvance.com.crowfoot.arvixe.com/account/signup). You can resize the height of your browser to see what I'm talking about.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: do you need smth like this http://plnkr.co/edit/M3HDYiPWl3P2t3St9xAd?p=preview ?

Answer (score 0):

Icemanind, What I did here to help your issue was this.
I added height to the body.
I set the background image not using the `body`tag and fixed it.
This way it now scrolls and the menu and footer stays fixed.
I also made the background image no repeat.

Is this what you were wanting.

Here is the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yewoyc71/3/)**.

The css link to your custom css didn't want to play ball in the fiddle, but in a mock up works fine.

```
<style>
body{
   height:2000px; 
}
.bg-image {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height:100vh;
    background: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/Albert_Einstein_Head.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -100;
}    
</style>
```

**Updated.**

Made a change to the Fiddle, I have added a transparent area to act as some content that is 2000px height.
I have added some margin to the bottom of this content. 
Have a look now and see if that is what you are after here.
Here is a full size **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yewoyc71/3/embedded/result/)**.

Comment: No, the footer and header were already staying in place. My problem is the content overlays the footer. I updated your fiddle to show you the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/yewoyc71/2/

Comment: When you look at the fiddle, notice how the content and the footer colide and the footer is on top of the content

Comment: You say you want the footer and header fixed. What am I missing here?  Explain what you want again please. If the footer is  fixed the content will scroll past the footer.

Comment: I do want it fixed. But I want the content itself to not hit the footer. Just like the header. The content starts AFTER the header. Similarly, I want the content to stop BEFORE the footer. If there is too much content, then the content should scroll. But it should scroll between the header and footer.

Comment: It works weird though. Full screen, I have two scroll bars now. If I resize it or pull it up on my tablet, I get 3 scroll bars.

Comment: Yes you're right looks odd with all those scrollbars. iframe within the window. But works better or as you want it to now which is great.